# Why android tag in SO has an image while others dont?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why do we have an image coming along with the android tag. Similarly it happens with google-maps and many more. Why don't we have an image for our beloved old friend "C" and etc ?

Comment: Does it mean "C" will never have a logo ?

Comment: "Never" is a long time. If it gets sponsored, sure.

Comment: It's unlikely to qualify for sponsoring though @Oded.